# diskpressure on node when deploying using kubernetes pod in pending state

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to bring up an app that was successfully run using docker swarm.  I am using Kubernetes.  I have a master VirtualBox VM and a node both Ubuntu.  The deployment and service with cpu and memory and limits set correctly ( or so I think).  The deployment and service succeeds but kubectl describe pods consistently shows event messages as

```sh
0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

I have checked a few things and increased the disk capacities on the master VM (and worker node though problem is shown only in master).  Reset the worker node using kubeadm and redeployed.

Also went thru similar questions and suggestions.
Looking for suggestions to resolve this toward Pod moving to ready or out of pending state

Thanks

deployment has cpu 500m and limit "1", memory 1Gi and limit 2Gi

Comment: what is the disk capacity of your worker node ?

Comment: from the VirtualBox Manager the worker node had 9.43Gb Actual and 182.1GB Virtual   The master which I spun just for this exercise is set to the same as I encountered these disk-pressure issues

Answer (score 3):

On the master/main, if you really want the pod scheduled there you can try un-tainting it.

```sh
$ kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

For the disk pressure taint, you may have something in your control plane from a previous instance of a node with the same name❓ If you know that you have enough space you can force remove it:

```sh
$ kubectl taint nodes --all node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure-
```

Keep in mind that this is a taint automatically added by the [node controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/#taint-based-evictions).

✌️

Comment: Thanks.  I wanted the pod to be deployed in the one worker node of the cluster.  That is what I am expecting the behavior to be.   I have restarted the master a few times, deleted all kubenode1 presence, rejoined the node and recreated the cluster, deployment and service.  This was to avoid the artifact issue that you mention.  I will try the commands you mention and update.  Thanks

Comment: I will check the disk artifacts you mention ( I think restart will not take care of that )

Comment: The disk-pressure issue kept up even if I increased capacity.  I also was not sure what files to remove to free up space. I cleared log files.

Comment: The disk-pressure issue kept up even if I increased capacity.  I also was not sure what files to remove to free up space. I cleared log files.  To isolate the issue and understand that it is due only because of disk space, I started a new VM for the worker node.  When I joined the only worker node the disk pressure issue immediately went away.    It was necessary to add a node selector in the deployment.yaml, apply the same tag to the node and then the kubectl describe pods -n <namespace> <podname> showed no errors or warnings.

Comment: sort of. Warning in pod description as something like this, 
Warning FailedCreatePodSandbox  error code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container <container id>: networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod <pod name>: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
I had to google for tips.  It looks like node cidr blocks were not set.  Ran a node patch for CIDR block assignment to the nodes 
``` kubectl patch node <NODE_NAME> -p '{"spec":{"podCIDR":"10.244.0.0/16"}}'``` Now the pod description is clean and no warnings.
kubectl logs showed something expected.

Comment: Thanks Rico for active tips.  If the networking issue should not happen (should there be a default behavior that would avoid the need for node cidr patch?), needs to be addressed please help in raising an appropriate ticket.

Comment: hmm networking should work out of the box. It looks like your cluster is in some undesirable state when it comes to networking. Did you try re-creating the cluster?